# Change caption title "Algorithmus 1" in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

Using **\begin{algorithm}** environment with only **\usepackage{algorithm2e}** in the preamble (and of course the usual packages for an article document),

the environment by default titles the algorithm "Algorithmus 1" upon render. Why? I want it to be "Algorithm 1".

Comment: Could you post a complete minimal code  with this problem?

Comment: Is this question still open ? The only answer seems to be the right way to do this, consider accepting it if it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown any code that we could process. I am guessing that you might be using the `czech` option. If so use the `\SetAlgorithmName` command after the `\usepackage...`

```
\SetAlgorithmName{<algorithmname>}{<algorithmautorefname>}{<list of algorithm name}
```

as explained in the manual (`texdoc algorithm2e`).